# Codeigniter on Ubuntu no welcome message

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, lamp, environment

I am trying to run CodeIgniter (2.14) on Ubuntu 13.10. I have put the files in "var/www/CodeIgniter" but when I enter the directory from the browser it does not show any welcome message as it did previously when working with CodeIgniter on Microsoft Windows 7. I have verified that PHP works on the environment with the function `phpinfo()` - PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2. The rights for the folder are 755 if that is of any importance.

I have tried to set the base URL to

```
 http://localhost/"myproject".
```

I have tried to re-download and "reinstall" CodeIgniter.

Guys I really could use your help I don't feel like running an windows environment in virtual box just for this and I definitely wouldn't like to install windows 8.1 just for this. All help is appreciated and considered constructive.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is rights on the 'var/www' folder. This can be fixed by the terminal or when unziping.

When unziping from the terminal like below it works

```
    sudo unzip CodeIgniter_2.1.4.zip -d /var/www/"desired folder"
```

Could also be fixed by changing rights after unpacking with GUI interface..

```
    sudo chmod 755 -R www
```

And to be able to use Netbeans as non sudo user change the folder owner

```
    sudo chown 'user-name' 'folder-name'
```

[image: Working Codeigniter]

Answer (score 1):

try to change permissions:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/Codeigniter
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove .htaccess from the root of myproject