# How to run codeigniter on Ubuntu

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu

I'm having trouble making my CodeIgniter project work in Ubuntu, since I've previously developed on Windows I am unfamiliar with the environment. My main problem is that I don't even see any error or warning that can help me determine what the problem is. It's just a blank screen. But I already run the symfony project on my laptop Symfony project was smoothly running. I also give the full permission on my CodeIgniter project.

Comment: Hi! you have to change recursive rights by the terminal... I had the identical problem a few days ago.. check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183602/codeigniter-on-ubuntu-no-welcome-message/20183809#20183809

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, one of the best tools for debugging websites is checking the log files.

The Apache log files are usually located in `/var/log/apache2/` and you can set up CodeIgniter to log errors to a file too.

Once you have that information, searching for a solution to your problem usually becomes much easier.