# Why CodeIgniter install error occur

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, frameworks, xampp

I already install CodeIgniter 3 at XAMPP/Ubuntu Envirement. When I do the same actions (Copy,start apache) and open localhost/ci dir on Widows I get welcome message. But on Ubuntu i'm getting a message:

> "Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please
>   open the following file and correct this: index.php"

I just installed CI and don't change any settings. 
What may be reason of error on UBUNTU (on Win all works fine)

my configurations:

> $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php';
>   [image: Filesystem and folders]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183602/codeigniter-on-ubuntu-no-welcome-message

Comment: The message says "your view folder path" or "your system/application folder path"?

Comment: The message says: "Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php" CI version is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for me. The way I did the installation was 
1. Create folder  (htdocs/ci)
2. Unzip installer to downloads
3. Paste installer files from /downloads to ci.

But when I did installation like 
1. Unzip install archive
2. RENAME folder I get from archive to CI all begin woking fine!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must open access for folder please try in your folder chmod -R 777 .

Comment: I was trying to do that before but it wasn't help to me.

Comment: go to your www root and chmod 755 your project folder. Then go inside project folder and execute this: sudo find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;